# How to make string when a sentence has quotation marks or inverted commas? Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, converters

For example I have a sentence such as:

```
Jamie's car broke "down" in the middle of the street
```

How can I convert this into a string without manually removing the quotation marks and inverted commas like:

```
'Jamies car broke down in the middle of the street'
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace()` one after other:

```
s = """Jamie's car broke "down" in the middle of the street"""

print(s.replace('\'', '').replace('"', ''))
# Jamies car broke down in the middle of the street
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use regex to remove all special characters from string as:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_str = """Jamie's car broke "down" in the middle of the street"""

>>> re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+', '', my_str)
'Jamies car broke down in the middle of the street'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
oldstr = """Jamie's car broke "down" in the middle of the street""" #Your problem string
newstr = oldstr.replace('\'', '').replace('"', '')) #New string using replace()
print(newstr) #print result
```

This returns:

```
Jamies car broke down in the middle of the street
```